# FastReport 2.54, align 2 Memo object horizontaly to each other

Tags: delphi, printing, fastreport

I'm using FR 2.54 and I should align 2 Memo object next to each other. The first one (MemoLeft, on the left) AutoWidth property is True. I tried to change the second memo (MemoRight, on the right) Left property in the OnBeforePrint event:

```
MemoRight.Left := MemoLeft.Left + MemoLeft.Width;
```

but the MemoLeft width is always the designed value, instead of the value should be after the width recalculated (AutoWidth = True).

Any solution how can I manage to position the second Memo to the first MEmo right edge?

I could use RichView, but the result looks very ugly on my printers, so I don't want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set memo's BandAlign properties to baLeft 
Place memos on the band in its creation order

Comment: I tried, but those wasn't in creation order, so all of them mixed up. Will try your solution later on today and let you know. Thanks!